# Add command to Chrome to open selected host name in PuTTY

Tags: google-chrome, putty, google-chrome-extensions, cmd.exe, amazon-web-services

Every time I have to copy the AWS EC2 public DNS and open PuTTY and connect.

```
Public DNS: ec2.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

As an alternative, how can I add an on select this public DNS and right show option open with PuTTY for Chrome [`ec2.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`] (like for example "Search Google for 'something'")
and then on click run an command in cmd say like `putty --default-profile  selectPublicDNS`

Please give me an idea an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the [Context Menu Search](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/context-menu-search/ocpcmghnefmdhljkoiapafejjohldoga) Chrome Extension.

It can pass the selected text to URLs only though. So you have to use a URL like `ssh://%s/` and associate PuTTY with the `ssh://` protocol.

PuTTY unfortunately [does not associate itself](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/wishlist/ssh-url-scheme.html). But you can do it manually. See MSDN article [Registering an Application to a URI Scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)).

---

You can go even a step further and create a user script that turns the host name to clickable `ssh://` link.

Inspired by your question, I've wrote a user script to [inject SFTP link "Open in WinSCP" to Amazon EC2 management console](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_injecting_sftp_ftp_url_to_page). You can easily modify it for the `ssh://` and "Open in PuTTY".

---

Though the above passes a whole URL to PuTTY command-line. And PuTTY does not understand the `ssh://` prefix. So you would have to add a wrapper script that strips the `ssh://` and passes only a user and a host to the PuTTY.

For that see:
https://johnsofteng.wordpress.com/2009/05/12/launch-putty-from-browser/

See also [Can PuTTY open SSH link similar to Terminal for Macintosh?](https://superuser.com/q/886164/213663)

---

[WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) 5.9 (and newer) [registers itself to handle the `ssh://` URL](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_url#handling) and [opens the session specified by the URL in PuTTY](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_putty#url).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*