# Can PuTTY open SSH link similar to Terminal for Macintosh?

Tags: windows, ssh, putty

I’ve got a SSH link (`ssh://`) in [1Password that if I was using a Macintosh](https://guides.agilebits.com/1password-mac-kb/4/en/topic/managing-ssh-logins) I could just click and have it open a session in Terminal. Is there a way to click an SSH link (`ssh://`) in Windows and have PuTTY open up the session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PuTTY unfortunately [does not associate itself](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/wishlist/ssh-url-scheme.html) with the `ssh://` URLs.

You can associate an application with a protocol manually. See the MSDN article [Registering an Application to a URI Scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)).

Basically you add a registry key like:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh]
@="URL: SSH Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PuTTY\\PuTTY.exe\",0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PuTTY\\PuTTY.exe\""
```

Though the above passes a whole URL to the PuTTY command-line. And PuTTY does not understand the `ssh://` prefix. So you would have to add a wrapper script that strips the `ssh://` and passes only a user and a host to PuTTY.

For that see:
https://johnsofteng.wordpress.com/2009/05/12/launch-putty-from-browser/

---

I do not know 1Password, but a similar application [KeePass](https://keepass.info/) can parse the URL and pass only its certain parts to the application. So it can strip the `ssh://` for you.

See [KeePass override rules](https://keepass.info/help/base/autourl.html#override).

---

On Windows, [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) 5.9 and newer [registers itself to handle the `ssh://` URL](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_url#handling) and [opens the session specified by the URL in PuTTY](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_putty#url).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*