# Launching PuTTY from web browser without having .reg file

Tags: ssh, putty

I was looking to launch PuTTY from web browser. Most of the solutions I got was to create a `ssh.reg` file which contains `ssh://` mapping and has to be registered in the registry ([HTML code to open putty client from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17670067/html-code-to-open-putty-client-from-browser)). I do not have the Admin rights. I am not able to merge the `.reg` file. So I am looking for an alternative solution that does not require a merging of `.reg` file. Is it possible to achieve through batch file directly? Or some other way around.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need Administrator rights to register the `ssh://` mapping.

Just create the mapping in your account registry hive.

Instead of:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh]
```

use:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ssh]
```

Except for the root key, the rest is the same as with machine-wide registration.
See for example [Can PuTTY open SSH link similar to Terminal for Macintosh?](https://superuser.com/q/886164/213663)

---

Alternatively, you can use a browser-specific solution.

For example in Mozilla Firefox go to *Tools > Options > Applications*.