# How do I configure telnet: or ssh: URIs to run in Putty?

Tags: windows-10, putty, telnet, protocol, uri

When I click a link like **telnet:pi@myraspberrypi** or **ssh:pi@myraspberrypi** I want it to open Putty and initiate the connection.  How can I do this in Windows 10?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can PuTTY open SSH link similar to Terminal for Macintosh?](http://superuser.com/questions/886164/can-putty-open-ssh-link-similar-to-terminal-for-macintosh)